# Publishing RabbitMq on Pivotal using docker image

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, port, cloud-foundry

Trying to publish rabbitMq on Pivotal using a docker image. 
After pushing the docker image it trying to build the rabbitMq enviroment but 
eventually after 5 mins it fails with the following error

> [HEALTH/0] ERR Failed to make TCP connection to port 5671: connection refused; 
>   Failed to make TCP connection to port 15671: 
>   connection refused 2020-01-08T12:07:12.10+0000
>
> [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.

I am assuming it is not able to assign ports?

Within my image file I have the following config for ExposedPorts. Am I missing anything in the config which can tell pivotal to assign specific ports etc?

```
 "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "25672/tcp": {},
                "4369/tcp": {},
                "5671/tcp": {},
                "5672/tcp": {}
            },
```

Comment: Are you trying to run RabbitMQ as an app on CF? That's probably not what you want, since it's a service, but if you want to push ahead you might be able to get it working with TCP ports and custom port mappings: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/custom-ports.html#procedure. With your docker container it will start with the lowest number port exposed: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/docker.html#run-monitor

Comment: @DanielMikusa I am trying to run rabbitMQ as a docker container on pivotal. I have tried with custom port mappings etc and none of them seem to work :(

Comment: Have you specifically tried the process I linked to above? The output you've posted above does not indicate that. If you have tried that process, please update your question with the step-by-step instructions and exactly what happens at each step up till you hit a problem. The more output you include the better we can help. Also, I will say again what you're trying to isn't really the best way to deploy RabbitMQ. I suspect you can make it work, but it's going to be more work than it would normally be to run an app on PCF.

Comment: One other thing,"Pivotal" isn't software product. It is a company with many software products. I assumed you're talking about Pivotal Cloud Foundry from context, but it would be helpful if you give specifics like exact product & version of software you're running. Thanks